# R: Loading data from folder with multiple files

Tags: r

I have a folder with multiple files to load:

[image]

Every file is a list. And I want to combine all the lists loaded in a single list. I am using the following code (the variable loaded every time from a file is called `TotalData`) :

```
Filenames <- paste0('DATA3_',as.character(1:18))
Data <- list()
for (ii in Filenames){
      load(ii)
      Data <- append(Data,TotalData)
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to write it? For example using apply functions?

Comment: Instead of `paste0('DATA3_',as.character(1:18))` you may want to use `list.files(".", pattern="^DATA3_")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply`. I assume that your files have been stored using `save`, because you use `load` to get them. I create two files to use in my example as follows:

```
TotalData<-list(1:10)
save(TotalData,file="DATA3_1")
TotalData<-list(11:20)
save(TotalData,file="DATA3_2")
```

And then I read them in by

```
Filenames <- paste0('DATA3_',as.character(1:2))
Data <- lapply(Filenames,function(fn) {
   load(fn)
   return (TotalData)
})
```

After this, `Data` will be a list that contains the lists from the files as its elements. Since you are using append in your example, I assume this is not what you want. I remove one level of nesting with

```
Data <- unlist(Data,recursive=FALSE)
```

For my two example files, this gave the same result as your code. Whether it is more elegant can be debated, but I would claim that it is more R-ish than the for-loop.